# How to enter BIOS setup in Sony Vaio SVT11125CGS

Tags: laptop, bios

I wanted to install Ubuntu in Sony Vaio T series 11.6 ultrabook (SVT11125CGS). But I could not get into BIOS setup to change by booting option to USB.

How do I get into BIOS setup?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this will be helpful

http://www.sony-asia.com/microsite/vaio/htmlmanuals/20123Q/SVD1121/eng/contents/04/21/02/02.html

so technically you use assist button when system is off...... than from rescue select the bios :-)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: On mine (E series), in addition to pressing the assist button to power on, you have to keep mashing F2 until it says "Assist menu loading" at the VAIO logo.

Answer (score 4):

F2 does not work on my **svt14112cxs**, instead with the computer off, press the "assist" button and then select BIOS in the menu.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm assuming the link in the accepted answer says the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

T series laptops have an assist button which should be pressed to get the option to Enter Setup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://esupport.sony.com/docs/pc/SVT1111_1311_series/EN/index.html), under "Setting/Changing the Power-on Password" they mention it's the usual <kbd>F2</kbd>:

> Turn on your VAIO computer and press the F2 key repeatedly until the VAIO logo disappears.
> ...
> The BIOS setup screen appears. If the screen does not appear, restart the computer and try again.

Specifically regarding booting from external devices they provide this instruction:

> You can boot your VAIO computer from external devices, such as an optical disc drive or a USB floppy disk drive, by using the BIOS function.
>
> 1. Connect an external device to your VAIO computer and turn on the computer.
> 2. Press the F11 key repeatedly until the VAIO logo disappears.
>
> The booting process from the external device starts. If your VAIO computer does not boot up,  restart the computer and try again.

Comment: both of these options seem not to work in my machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this model seems to be different in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 8, the usual "press some key at boot" spiel won't work.
You need to do a special boot via Windows settings.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzELLtnfO8Q

Answer (score 0):

Just press the ASSIST button when your computer is off and it will turn the computer on and direct you to the wizard page which will guide you through the process. Just follow the wizard as what you want to do.